# Ошибка при запуске кода на C в VS Code

Tags: c, отладка, visual-studio-code

При запуске программы VS Code выдает ошибку

```
unable to start debugging unexpected gdb output from command:"-environment-cd C:\Users\..." ... No such file or directory
```

Как ее исправить?

launch.json

```
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "g++.exe build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": true,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++.exe build active file"
    },
    {
        "name": "g++ build & run active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${fileDirname}\\${fileBasenameNoExtension}.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false, //set to true to see output in cmd instead
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "g++ build & run active file"
    }
]
```

Comment: `launch.json` в студию.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, прошу

Comment: Такое ощущение, что команда `g++ build & run active file` скопипасчена с команды запуска.

Answer (score 0):

Если стоит MinGW, то посмотрите, не содержит ли путь до исполняемого файла пробелов, специальных знаков, русских символов или цифр.

Сталкивался с этой проблемой. MinGW очень не любит такое. Лучше всего, чтобы путь до .cpp или .exe содержал ТОЛЬКО латинские символы без пробелов, цифр и других посторонних символов.